How can I use XQuery to generate co-occurrence lists of elements of the same type?
I have an XML file of a book, with persons tagged within chapters. I am trying to use XQuery 3.1, running in oXygen, to calculate co-occurrences (when certain characters show up in the same chapter) to create a table of edges data to feed into network analysis. A simplified XML might look like this:
<book>
  <chapter n="I">
    <person>Susan</person>
    <person>Victor</person>
  </chapter>
  <chapter n="II">
    <person>Victor</person>
    <person>Susan</person>
    <person>Victor</person>
    <person>Iago</person>
    <person>Victor</person>
  </chapter>
  <chapter n="III">
    <person>Susan</person>
    <person>Iago</person>
    <person>Scott</person>
    <person>Susan</person>
  </chapter>
</book>

What I need to create is a csv file that lists distinct pairs of persons and the count of chapters in which they occur together, like so:
From,To,Chapters
Susan,Victor,2
Susan,Iago,2
Victor,Iago,1
Susan,Iago,1

Here's what I have so far:
declare option saxon:output "method=text";  
declare variable $linefeed := "&#10;";  
concat('From,To,Chapters', $linefeed,
string-join(
let $persons := //person/string()=>distinct-values()
for $person in $persons
    let $pers-chapters := //chapter[.//person/string()=$person]
    for $pers-chapter in $pers-chapters
        let $chap-num := $pers-chapter/data(@n)
        let $fellow-occupants := $pers-chapter//person/string()=>distinct-values()
            for $fellow-occupant in $fellow-occupants
            where $fellow-occupant!=($person) 
            return concat ($person,',', $fellow-occupant, ',', $chap-num),
            $linefeed))

This returns:
From,To,Chapters
Susan,Victor,I
Susan,Victor,II
Susan,Iago,II
Susan,Iago,III
Susan,Scott,III
Victor,Susan,I
Victor,Susan,II
Victor,Iago,II
Iago,Susan,II
Iago,Victor,II
Iago,Susan,III
Iago,Scott,III
Scott,Susan,III
Scott,Iago,III

So I have several problems. What I'm really trying to do is, first, to isolate each distinct pair of persons (so if I have Susan,Victor I do not also want to see Victor,Susan); and I'm not sure how to find and return distinct pairs of nodes of the same type in the text. (You'll see that I have called the first person in the return line $person and the second one $fellow-occupant. I don't know how else to go about this.)
Second, what I have so far creates a new line for each shared chapter, since that's what the second for-loop does. But what I need is for the XQuery to locate and count the chapters for each distinct pair and output a single line for the pair with the count of chapters.
Any help would be much appreciated! I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a long time and I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental at the conceptual level.

Great question! There are probably several ways to approach this.
Personally, I would start by identifying all of the people in a single variable:
let $distinct-people := //person => distinct-values() => sort()

This would yield a sequence of 4 names:
"Iago",
"Scott",
"Susan",
"Victor"

Then, I would construct a sequence of the distinct pairs:
let $distinct-pairs := 
    for $person at $n in $distinct-people
    (: select only the remaining people in the list :)
    let $others := subsequence($distinct-people, $n + 1)
    return
        $others ! array { $person, . }

This would yield 5 arrays:
[Iago,Scott],
[Iago,Susan],
[Iago,Victor],
[Scott,Susan],
[Scott,Victor]

Next, I would iterate over these pairs and count the number of chapters where both characters appear, constructing a CSV row whenever there is at least one chapter:
let $rows := 
    for $pair in $distinct-pairs
    let $occurrences := //chapter[person = $pair?1 and person = $pair?2]
    let $count := count($occurrences) 
    where $count ge 1
    return
        string-join(($pair?1, $pair?2, $count), ",")

Finally, I would return the full CSV:
let $header := 'From,To,Chapters'
return
    string-join(($header, $rows), $linefeed)

This returns:
From,To,Chapters
Iago,Scott,1
Iago,Susan,2
Iago,Victor,1
Scott,Susan,1
Susan,Victor,2

Putting the whole query together:
xquery version "3.1";

declare option saxon:output "method=text";  

let $distinct-people := //person => distinct-values() => sort()
let $distinct-pairs := 
    for $person at $n in $distinct-people
    let $others := subsequence($distinct-people, $n + 1)
    return
        $others ! array { $person, . }
let $rows := 
    for $pair in $distinct-pairs
    let $occurrences := //chapter[person = $pair?1 and person = $pair?2]
    let $count := count($occurrences) 
    where $count ge 1
    return
        string-join(($pair?1, $pair?2, $count), ",")
let $header := 'From,To,Chapters'
let $linefeed := "&#10;"
return
    string-join(($header, $rows), $linefeed)


A fascinating problem.
Here's my attempt:
(for $chap in /book/chapter
 let $sorted-names := sort(distinct-values($chap/person))
 for $n at $pos in $sorted-names
 for $m in subsequence($sorted-names, $pos+1)
 return map{concat($n, ',', $m): $chap/@n})
  => map:merge(map{'duplicates':'combine'})
  => map:for-each(function($key, $value) {
                     concat($key, ',', count($value))
                  })
  => sort()
  => string-join('&#xa;')

producing this output:
Iago,Scott,1
Iago,Susan,2
Iago,Victor,1
Scott,Susan,1
Susan,Victor,2

What this does is first, for each chapter to build a map from pairs-of-names to chapter number; then merge these maps combining duplicates into a single entry containing the list of chapters for each pair, then to iterate over this map outputing the size of the list of chapters.
The processing for each chapter is quadratic in the number of distinct names appearing in that chapter, but the overall processing is effectively linear in the number of chapters, which I think makes it more scaleable than some of the other solutions proposed.
== LATER ==
Prompted by the mention of Iago, I ran this on Othello.xml, changing the paths to select speakers in each scene. The results (in 124ms):
All,CASSIO,2
All,DESDEMONA,2
All,EMILIA,1
All,GRATIANO,1
All,IAGO,2
All,LODOVICO,1
All,MONTANO,2
All,OTHELLO,2
All,RODERIGO,1
BIANCA,CASSIO,3
BIANCA,Clown,1
BIANCA,DESDEMONA,2
BIANCA,EMILIA,2
BIANCA,GRATIANO,1
BIANCA,IAGO,3
BIANCA,LODOVICO,2
BIANCA,OTHELLO,3
BIANCA,RODERIGO,1
BRABANTIO,CASSIO,1
BRABANTIO,DESDEMONA,1
BRABANTIO,DUKE OF VENICE,1
BRABANTIO,First Officer,2
BRABANTIO,First Senator,1
BRABANTIO,IAGO,3
BRABANTIO,Messenger,1
BRABANTIO,OTHELLO,2
BRABANTIO,RODERIGO,3
BRABANTIO,Sailor,1
BRABANTIO,Second Senator,1
BRABANTIO,Senator,1
CASSIO,Clown,2
CASSIO,DESDEMONA,6
CASSIO,EMILIA,6
CASSIO,First Gentleman,1
CASSIO,First Musician,1
CASSIO,First Officer,1
CASSIO,Fourth Gentleman,1
CASSIO,GRATIANO,2
CASSIO,IAGO,9
CASSIO,LODOVICO,3
CASSIO,MONTANO,3
CASSIO,OTHELLO,8
CASSIO,RODERIGO,4
CASSIO,Second Gentleman,1
CASSIO,Second Gentlemen,1
CASSIO,Third Gentleman,1
Clown,DESDEMONA,1
Clown,EMILIA,2
Clown,First Musician,1
Clown,IAGO,2
Clown,OTHELLO,1
DESDEMONA,DUKE OF VENICE,1
DESDEMONA,EMILIA,6
DESDEMONA,First Gentleman,1
DESDEMONA,First Officer,1
DESDEMONA,First Senator,1
DESDEMONA,Fourth Gentleman,1
DESDEMONA,GRATIANO,1
DESDEMONA,IAGO,8
DESDEMONA,LODOVICO,3
DESDEMONA,MONTANO,3
DESDEMONA,Messenger,1
DESDEMONA,OTHELLO,9
DESDEMONA,RODERIGO,4
DESDEMONA,Sailor,1
DESDEMONA,Second Gentleman,1
DESDEMONA,Second Gentlemen,1
DESDEMONA,Second Senator,1
DESDEMONA,Senator,1
DESDEMONA,Third Gentleman,1
DUKE OF VENICE,First Officer,1
DUKE OF VENICE,First Senator,1
DUKE OF VENICE,IAGO,1
DUKE OF VENICE,Messenger,1
DUKE OF VENICE,OTHELLO,1
DUKE OF VENICE,RODERIGO,1
DUKE OF VENICE,Sailor,1
DUKE OF VENICE,Second Senator,1
DUKE OF VENICE,Senator,1
EMILIA,First Gentleman,1
EMILIA,First Musician,1
EMILIA,Fourth Gentleman,1
EMILIA,GRATIANO,2
EMILIA,IAGO,7
EMILIA,LODOVICO,3
EMILIA,MONTANO,2
EMILIA,OTHELLO,7
EMILIA,RODERIGO,3
EMILIA,Second Gentleman,1
EMILIA,Second Gentlemen,1
EMILIA,Third Gentleman,1
First Gentleman,Fourth Gentleman,1
First Gentleman,IAGO,1
First Gentleman,MONTANO,1
First Gentleman,OTHELLO,1
First Gentleman,RODERIGO,1
First Gentleman,Second Gentleman,1
First Gentleman,Second Gentlemen,1
First Gentleman,Third Gentleman,1
First Musician,IAGO,1
First Officer,First Senator,1
First Officer,IAGO,2
First Officer,Messenger,1
First Officer,OTHELLO,2
First Officer,RODERIGO,2
First Officer,Sailor,1
First Officer,Second Senator,1
First Officer,Senator,1
First Senator,IAGO,1
First Senator,Messenger,1
First Senator,OTHELLO,1
First Senator,RODERIGO,1
First Senator,Sailor,1
First Senator,Second Senator,1
First Senator,Senator,1
Fourth Gentleman,IAGO,1
Fourth Gentleman,MONTANO,1
Fourth Gentleman,OTHELLO,1
Fourth Gentleman,RODERIGO,1
Fourth Gentleman,Second Gentleman,1
Fourth Gentleman,Second Gentlemen,1
Fourth Gentleman,Third Gentleman,1
GRATIANO,IAGO,2
GRATIANO,LODOVICO,2
GRATIANO,MONTANO,1
GRATIANO,OTHELLO,2
GRATIANO,RODERIGO,1
Gentleman,IAGO,1
Gentleman,OTHELLO,1
IAGO,LODOVICO,3
IAGO,MONTANO,3
IAGO,Messenger,1
IAGO,OTHELLO,11
IAGO,RODERIGO,7
IAGO,Sailor,1
IAGO,Second Gentleman,1
IAGO,Second Gentlemen,1
IAGO,Second Senator,1
IAGO,Senator,1
IAGO,Third Gentleman,1
LODOVICO,MONTANO,1
LODOVICO,OTHELLO,4
LODOVICO,RODERIGO,1
MONTANO,OTHELLO,3
MONTANO,RODERIGO,2
MONTANO,Second Gentleman,1
MONTANO,Second Gentlemen,1
MONTANO,Third Gentleman,1
Messenger,OTHELLO,1
Messenger,RODERIGO,1
Messenger,Sailor,1
Messenger,Second Senator,1
Messenger,Senator,1
OTHELLO,RODERIGO,6
OTHELLO,Sailor,1
OTHELLO,Second Gentleman,1
OTHELLO,Second Gentlemen,1
OTHELLO,Second Senator,1
OTHELLO,Senator,1
OTHELLO,Third Gentleman,1
RODERIGO,Sailor,1
RODERIGO,Second Gentleman,1
RODERIGO,Second Gentlemen,1
RODERIGO,Second Senator,1
RODERIGO,Senator,1
RODERIGO,Third Gentleman,1
Sailor,Second Senator,1
Sailor,Senator,1
Second Gentleman,Second Gentlemen,1
Second Gentleman,Third Gentleman,1
Second Gentlemen,Third Gentleman,1
Second Senator,Senator,1


This is my approach. In the end, the formatting as CSV is missing, but the idea should be clear.
declare variable $book :=
  <book>
    <chapter n="I">
      <person>Susan</person>
      <person>Victor</person>
    </chapter>
    <chapter n="II">
      <person>Victor</person>
      <person>Susan</person>
      <person>Victor</person>
      <person>Iago</person>
      <person>Victor</person>
    </chapter>
    <chapter n="III">
      <person>Susan</person>
      <person>Iago</person>
      <person>Scott</person>
      <person>Susan</person>
    </chapter>
  </book>;

declare function local:get-distinct-pairs($chapter as element()) as element()* {
  let $person-names := for $name in distinct-values($chapter/person/text())
                       order by $name
                       return $name
  for $name1 in $person-names
  for $name2 in $person-names
  where $name1 lt $name2
  return
    element pair
    {
      attribute name1 {$name1},
      attribute name2 {$name2},
      attribute key {concat($name1, '|', $name2)}
    }
};

let $pairs-per-chapter :=
  for $chapter in $book/chapter
  let $chapter-nr := $chapter/data(@n)
  let $pairs := local:get-distinct-pairs($chapter)
  return 
    element pairs
    {
      attribute chapter-nr {$chapter-nr},
      $pairs
    }

let $distinct-pairs :=
  for $key in distinct-values($pairs-per-chapter/pair/data(@key))
  let $pair := $pairs-per-chapter/pair[@key = $key]
  let $pair-count as xs:integer := count($pair)
  let $first-pair := $pair[1]
  order by $key
  return 
    element { node-name($first-pair)}
    {
      attribute pair-count {$pair-count},
      $first-pair/@*,
      $first-pair/node()
    }

return 
  <debug>
    <pairs-per-chapter>{$pairs-per-chapter}</pairs-per-chapter>
    <distinct-pairs>{$distinct-pairs}</distinct-pairs>
  </debug>
  

The result is
<debug>
  <pairs-per-chapter>
    <pairs chapter-nr="I">
      <pair name1="Susan" name2="Victor" key="Susan|Victor"/>
    </pairs>
    <pairs chapter-nr="II">
      <pair name1="Iago" name2="Susan" key="Iago|Susan"/>
      <pair name1="Iago" name2="Victor" key="Iago|Victor"/>
      <pair name1="Susan" name2="Victor" key="Susan|Victor"/>
    </pairs>
    <pairs chapter-nr="III">
      <pair name1="Iago" name2="Scott" key="Iago|Scott"/>
      <pair name1="Iago" name2="Susan" key="Iago|Susan"/>
      <pair name1="Scott" name2="Susan" key="Scott|Susan"/>
    </pairs>
  </pairs-per-chapter>
  <distinct-pairs>
    <pair pair-count="1" name1="Iago" name2="Scott" key="Iago|Scott"/>
    <pair pair-count="2" name1="Iago" name2="Susan" key="Iago|Susan"/>
    <pair pair-count="1" name1="Iago" name2="Victor" key="Iago|Victor"/>
    <pair pair-count="1" name1="Scott" name2="Susan" key="Scott|Susan"/>
    <pair pair-count="2" name1="Susan" name2="Victor" key="Susan|Victor"/>
  </distinct-pairs>
</debug>

The function get-distinct-pairs() calculates the distinct pairs for each chapter. The convention here is, that the first name ist lexicographically lower than the second name.
Additionally, we create a string key for each pair by concatenating the names with pipe as separator.
Example:
<pair name1="Susan" name2="Victor" key="Susan|Victor"/>

The result of function get-distinct-pairs() can be seen in the debug output at /debug/pairs-per-chapter.
Then we use this sequence together with the key we just calculated to get the distinct pair keys. And with that we can search for the pairs with this key. The number of result pairs per key is the searched number of the pair, in how many chapters it occurs.

Saxon also supports XSLT where you can group the chapters by the pairs:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/book">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="chapter" group-by="let $persons := person => distinct-values() => sort() return for $p1 in $persons return for $p2 in $persons[$p1 lt .] return $p1 || ',' || $p2">
      <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), count(current-group())" separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group> 
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

